# Crashing in certain specific situations from "intel_do_flush_lock_failed" in all source engine games

Tags: games, intel-graphics, steam, crash

I've been plagued by a strange issue since an update about a month ago, which causes source-engine-based games to freeze up my system (sound loop, entire desktop becomes unresponsive, framerate drops to about 0.125 fps (yes, one frame per 4 seconds) before finally closing after about 15 seconds, and giving me back control of my computer).

The causes of this crash are not "random"; although they appear to have very little in common, they all produce the same error. It can be triggered by spawning a prop, or in the middle of being chased by an NPC, or travelling to a certain part of a map.

**Here are a couple things I have determined to reliably cause the crash (there are more than this):**

Garry's Mod: Attempting to spawn display_cooler01a via the 'q' menu (spawning it with the tool gun works, and allows it to be spawned via the menu thereafter without error, strangely.)

Team Fortress 2: Dying, or sometimes when turning a corner or on the character selection menu.

Garry's mod: Walking up the first wooden bridge in gm_bobomb_battlefield_h1 (The terminal output included with this post was produced using this method)

**I have tried:**

- Reinstalling my entire operating system (Xubuntu) and reinstalling steam
- Validating local files for all of these games (reports 'successful' validation)
- Enabling "Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode" in "Additional Drivers" under Software and Update settings.

None of these work, the crash still occurs, and can still be triggered by the exact same actions.
I have been able to get around these crashes by forcing steam and these games to use software rendering, but this is extremely slow, obviously...

I've attached a link to a Google Drive folder where I've uploaded some info that I hope will be useful. If there is no solution, I'm still curious if anyone else is having this issue, or knows what is causing it (related to sloppy patches for spectre/meltdown?), just to put my mind at ease.

[Output of running steam in terminal (from Gmod launch time to crash), lspci and uname -a](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KZ4VqijDbTJhF0ckCsSekdNFjvFmxJ_4?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of digging around, I have actually answered my own question!

If anyone on a Dell Inspiron 5559, I managed to fix it by adding the repo

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu xenial main` to 
 apt,

and running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri`

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102226

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/install-mesa-17-2-ubuntu

Sorry to bother anyone who stumbled across this.